# How to make sprites respond to contact events but not collision events (SpriteKit)?

Tags: ios, swift, cocos2d-iphone, sprite-kit

Is it possible to make sprites in Swift respond only to contact events, ignoring collision events? We set the `dynamic` property to `false` for one of the sprites, but it didn't trigger the `didBeginContact` method when another sprite contacted it.

In other words, we want to get notified in `didBeginContact` when another sprite contacts an object, but we don't want the sprite to experience physics (e.g., no bouncing or moving on collision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set collisionbitmask to 0 on both sprites. But set the contacttestbitmask to the opposite sprites categorybitmask

heres an example

heres the setup for my **Power Up**  this is a physics body that doesnt exhibit physics behavior

```
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: self.size)
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CategoryPowerup
    self.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = CategoryShip
    self.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0
    self.physicsBody!.dynamic = false
```

heres the setup for my **Ship** that gets the powerup

```
    let physicsBodyInset = CGRectInset(CGRectMake(0, 0, self.size.width, self.size.height), 2, 2)
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: physicsBodyInset.size)
    self.physicsBody!.restitution = 0
    self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = CategoryShip
```

Comment: What if we need spriteA to not exhibit physics but we need spriteB to exhibit physics? Just set the collisionbitmask to 0 on spriteA but not B? Thanks!

Comment: If you want something to be a physics body without exhibiting physics set dynamic to false and collisionbitmask to 0

Comment: When we set dynamic to false, the didBeginContact function doesn't get triggered for that sprite. We still want to get notified if there is a contact made ... just no physics. Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. It has nothing to do with dynamic. Just set the contacttestbitmask to the categorybitmask of the sprite you want to register a collision with

Comment: i added some sample code.. hopefully its useful to you

Comment: Also sent an email through your website re consulting if you're interested ... thanks again!